# SoapUI giving error as Malformed Request when Request is valid

Tags: xml, wcf, soap, soapui, xml-namespaces

Here is a snippet of xml generated by my .net code that is sent to a third party soap service endpoint.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
  <ProgramInterface 
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">  
    <vnsState_request xmlns="http://www.statewide.Request.com">
.....
....
...
```

This works thru code but when I put the exact same request that I pulled out from my debug breakpoint in SoapUI and send it to the same service it returns with XML malformed error as below

```
<faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
<faultstring>Malformed SOAP message</faultstring>
```

When I generate a sample request for the same operation I see this difference in the generated request XML

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:vns="http://www.statewide.Request.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <vns:VNSSTATEOperation>
         <vns:vnsState_request>
```

Why does SoapUI require those extra tags and why can't it use the request generated by my .Net code? And why does it require `vns:` pre-pended to every element along with those new elements?

```
<soapenv:Envelope >
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Regarding Extra Tags:** If you are hitting a SOAP service from any client, SOAP headers are required. You may find more details [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_soap.asp).
2. **Regarding Prefix:** It is not required if the default *namespace* is used which is in you `.net` case. Where as in the SoapUI, it is using explicit *namespace*, hence the `prefix` is used. You can find more details regarding the *namespace* [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp).

For instance, taking your example. Below both are same.

```
<vnsState_request xmlns="http://www.statewide.Request.com">
<!--the above one is using default namespace -->
```

and

```
<ns:vnsState_request xmlns:ns="http://www.statewide.Request.com">
<!--using explicit namespace "ns", hence the same is prefixed for the tag -->
```

And if you take a look at the one in SoapUI, it has added namespace in the first line itself. So, it using as you have shown.

Hope this helps.